Xcode showing different CFBundleShortVersionString and CFBundleVersion in general info compared to app
I have a project set up with Tuist. We include an xcconfig file with team and version informations.
The project runs just fine. The version informations we have set up in the xcconfig file is shown in the targets "General" tab correctly.


Now, when I run the app and print a debug log message with the versions, I get a different value. This is how I log at the start of the app:
    let appVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String ?? ""
    let appBuildVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String ?? ""

    RTLogger.misc.debug("App version: \(appVersion), Build version: \(appBuildVersion)")

Which prints this: App version: 1.0, Build version: 1 (which is the default information as if it had not been changed by the xcconfig file.
Also, upon archiving, I get a build showing me these version numbers as well.

What am I missing here?

OK, so I guess I learnt something new about Tuist today …
It's also quite obvious when you think about it–the setting is to be defined in the Tuist manifest itself–meaning:

in a terminal at the project level, do tuist edit
in there, specify CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString in the Project
there is no step 3 …


Future me will most likely find this useful at some point–perhaps others will too …

